# Checking for #N/A in Excel cell from VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm iterating through a range of cells which hold numbers with 2 decimal places. I need to check if the cell holds '#N/A', and if it does, I need to skip it. The problem is, when a cell holds a valid number, my if condition below throws a 'Type mismatch error'. How can I avoid this?

```
If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Publish").Range("G4").offset(offsetCount, 0).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
'do something
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, asked the question hastily. Casting LHS of expression as CVErr fixes it.

Comment: You can also use IsError(rg) if you're not concerned about the specific type of error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First check for an error (N/A value) and then try the comparisation against cvErr(). You are comparing two different things, a value and an error. This may work, but not always. Simply casting the expression to an error may result in similar problems because it is not a real error only the value of an error which depends on the expression.

```
If IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Publish").Range("G4").offset(offsetCount, 0).Value) Then
  If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Publish").Range("G4").offset(offsetCount, 0).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
    'do something
  End If
End If
```

Comment: There is also Application.IsNA, which you would use like: 'If Application.IsNA(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Publish").Range("G4").offset(offsetCount, 0).Value) Then'

Comment: Could not find the `Application.IsNA()` in excel 2010 @jtolle

Comment: @pablete: It's there! You can use either `Application.IsNA()` (which will not show up in VBA's little autocomplete suggestion), or `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA()`, which will. For example, try this in the Immediate window: `?application.isna([na()])`. You should get back `True`.

Comment: Ahh, ok, now it works (does not show on the auto complete feature), thanks a lot.

Comment: IMO, as the N/A error is part of all errors found by IsError, the first command suffice the asked need.  Only, it shall be negated to skip erroneous rows - If Not IsError(...) Then 'do something.