# How to skip over a section of code if two cells don't equal a certain value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a macro that copies data between multiple workbooks. A certain section of code needs to be run only in a specific situation. The problem is, whether or not that code is run, the code after it will ALWAYS need to run. For example:

```
'
If Range("B26").Value <> "#N/A" And Range("D26").Value <> "#N/A" Then
'
' Transfers Component Data
'
    Range("B28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Form.xls").Activate
    Range("O61:P61").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I71:J71").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10.00%"
    Range("A72:P72").Select
    Range("A1:A21").Select
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

End If

'
' Final_Transfer_Macro Macro
'
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Form.xls").Activate
    Range("F7:I7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1:A21").Select
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
```

The 'Transfers Component Data' section is the part that won't always be run. But everything before and after will always run.

Also, I don't care if `.Select` is slow, or `.Activate` is not ideal. So please don't lecture me.

Comment: I believe there is a separate problem with my code that is causing the problem, thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the code using so that only the section that won't always be run is (in an if statement) between **If** and **End If** like so:

```
If condition Then
    Do some Transfers Component code (if condition is true)
End If

Do some code
```

If this is not working (the Transfers Component is always executed) then it is most likely a problem with your condition statement(s) - they are always true

EDIT:

Just did a little search and to check for N/A you need to do two condition checks. One to check if there is an error in the value of the cell and another to check if it is equal to

```
If Not (IsError(Range("B26").Value) AND IsError(Range("D26").Value)) Then
    If Range("B26").Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA) And Range("D26").Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        Transfers Code Here
    End If
End If
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5143524/5111155)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking.  Just use an if statement.

```
'
' Transfers Component Data
'
If Range("B28").Value + Range("C28").Value <> someValue then 
    Range("B28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Form.xls").Activate
    Range("O61:P61").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I71:J71").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10.00%"
    Range("A72:P72").Select
    Range("A1:A21").Select
    Windows("Transfer Template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
End if

End if
'
' Final_Transfer_Macro Macro
'
```