# Copy & Paste values if cell value = "N/A"

Tags: excel, vba, replace, copy-paste

I want to copy and paste values to a range of cells but only if their value = "N/A". I want to leave the formulas as they are in all the cells that do not = "N/A".

In context, I have hundreds of VLOOKUPs. Example:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("L0"&MID(G$4,1,1)&"A0"&MID(G$4,1,1)&MID(G$4,3,2)&"-0"&$B6,Sheet1!$C:$D,2,FALSE),"N/A")
```

Is this possible with VBA?

Comment: You should use NA() instead of "N/A" in your formula, if you can. this would help to use ISERROR in VBA. This post can help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use real error values rather than string that only look like errors.  Secondly, `VLOOKUP` returns the `N/A` error directly if the lookup value is not found, so the `IFERROR` wrapper can be dispenced with. So the formula

```
=VLOOKUP("L0"&MID(G$4,1,1)&"A0"&MID(G$4,1,1)&MID(G$4,3,2)&"-0"&$B6,Sheet1!$C:$D,2,FALSE)
```

is sufficient as is.

To replace `N/A` results with error values, you can use this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Dim datV As Variant, datF As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Get range to process by any means you choose
    '  For example
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ' Copy data to variant arrays for efficiency
    datV = rngSrc.Value
    datF = rngSrc.Formula

    ' replace erroring formulas
    For i = 1 To UBound(datV, 1)
        If IsError(datV(i, 1)) Then
            If datV(i, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                datF(i, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' return data from variant arrays to sheet
    rngSrc.Formula = datF



End Sub
```

If you really want to use strings rather than true error values, adapt the `If` lines to suit

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loop through all cells in a range, you can use `SpecialCells` to shorten working with the `=NA()`cells

This also open up a non-VBA method (if the only error cells are `NA`, ie no `Div#/0`)

1. The first two methods below (manual and code) deal with the situation where you only gave `NA` cells
2. the third uses `SpecialCells` to focus on only the cells that need to be tested, before then running a check for `NA` before making updates

***option1***

Manual selection of formula cells that evaluate to errors

- Select the range of interest
- Press [F5].
- Click *Special*
- Select *Formulas*
- check only *Errors*

***option2***

VBA updating formula cells that evaluate to errors

*code*

```
Sub Shorter()
Dim rng1 As Range
On Error Resume Next
' All error formulas in column A
Set rng1 = Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'update with new value (could be value or formulae)
rng1.Value = "new value"
End Sub
```

***option 3***

Test for `=NA()`

```
Sub TestSpecificRegion()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim X
Dim lngRow As Long

On Error Resume Next
' All error formulas in column A
Set rng1 = Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'update with new value (could be value or formulae)
For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
    If rng2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        X = rng2.Value2
        For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
            If X(lngRow, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then X(lngRow, 1) = "new value"
        Next
        rng2.Value = X
    Else
        If rng2.Value2 = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then rng2.Value = "new value"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```