# Find the value of #N/A

Tags: vba, excel

im trying to look for #N/A value in my data but im getting error.. not sure how to assign the value of "#N/A" into my criteria..

```
lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim a As Integer


For a = 6 To lastrow2
  If Range("C" & a).Value <> "#N/A" Then
  Rows(a).Font.Strikethrough = True
  End If

Next a
```

Comment: You might want to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for #N/A in Excel cell from VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code)