# VBA detect and compare string

Tags: vba, string, compare

I managed to get the answer after I run this code.
But I still received Runtime error 13 message. Can u help me to resolve it? @PEH

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim str As String

 str = "Attention for shipment on track"

 Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

 Dim lastrows As Long
 lastrows = ws.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim i As Long
 For i = 2 To lastrows
    If InStr(1, ws.cells(i, 43).Value, str) > 0 Then
        ws.cells(i, 63).Value = "OK"
    End If
  Next i
```

Comment: I don't know if that will solve your problem but i'd change `If InStr(ws.cells(i, 43).Value, "str") Then` for `If ws.Cells(i, 43) Like "*" & str & "*" Then`

Comment: That must be, but using the `Like` operator in this context would be enough for her goal, right?

Comment: Which **line** shows this error message? If you cannot tell the line of code that produces that error we cannot help you.

Comment: This line  "  If InStr(1, ws.cells(i, 43).Value, str) > 0 Then  ". I still got result but when I tried to debug, the error message Run-tim13 (Type mismatch) pops out. Is there anything I missed out?

Comment: @kelsey what is the value of `ws.cells(i, 43).Value` in case of the error?

Comment: When it detects "#N/A" in the cell value, the code then break and give me that error. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @kelsey well that cell has not a text but an error as content. You cannot search in errors for a string. Therefore either fix your formula errors or make sure you don't run `instr` on cells that contain errors: See [Checking for #N/A in Excel cell from VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code)

Comment: It works now. Thanks alot!

Comment: yeah...done! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `InStr` returns a position and not `True` or `False` what is needed for the `If` statement. Also `"str"` is litterally looking for these 3 characters `"str"` if you mean the variable `str` you need to remove the quotes here.

<s>Finally the first parameter of the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) is the start position.</s>
As @FunThomas pointed out in the comments the `Start` parameter in the beginning of the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) is optional and indeed can be omited.

```
Option Explicit

Sub track()        
    Dim str As String
    str = "Attention for shipment on track"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

    Dim lastrows As Long
    lastrows = ws.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastrows         
        If InStr(1, ws.cells(i, 43).Value, str) > 0 Then
            ws.cells(i, 63).Value = "OK"  
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Make sure always to use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** variables properly.

Comment: You can omit the starting position for `InStr` in VBA (even if it is the first parameter).

Comment: @FunThomas huh, indeed, you are right. I was 100 % sure if you omit a paramater in the beginning you have to use named parameters instead to make it work. Another example in my list of how strange VBA sometimes is. Fixed it!

Comment: Any number other than 0 in vba returns true. Therefore, it is not necessary to distinguish between true or false by comparing with >0. In the vlookup function, 0,1 is used instead of FALSE and TRUE.

Comment: Boolean Data Type (Visual Basic) refer [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type)

Comment: @Dy.Lee You are right, that's not an issue, as `0` is defined to be `False` and `True` is defined not to be `False`. I got confused because in VBA `True` casts to `-1` and in formulas `True` casts to `1`. But yes, technically that's not an issue. Still I would prefer to be clear here not to lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: I managed to get the answer I want, but the Run-time error 13 message box still pops up. How can i fix it? @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @kelsey Please include in your question in which line you get the error.