# Getting an Error while using If Condition to remove specific Values from Cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to remove `0` and `#N/A"` from the cell but when i run the code it gives me an error Type Mismatch.

Can someone please look into the issue that why an error is occur. Your help will be appreciated.

```
 If sht3.Range("B4") = 0 Or "#N/A" Then
 sht3.Range("B4") = ""
 End If
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code. You can use `Application.IsNA` but you need to move the check for `0` into an `ElseIf` (assuming that the cell can't be any other type of error, e.g. #DIV/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `#N/A` is not text. Attempting to compare an error value to a number or text is an automatic type mismatch.

You can use `Application.IsNA`, but note that you need to move the check for 0 into an `ElseIf` (this assumes the cell cannot be any other type of error, e.g. `#DIV/0`).

```
With sht3.Range("B4")
    If Application.IsNA(.Value) Then
        .Value = ""
    ElseIf .Value = 0
        .Value = ""
    End If
End With
```

Comment: @Mento note that `Application.IsNA` is getting Excel's calculation engine involved to evaluate the `ISNA` Excel function. The all-VBA equivalent would be to check whether `IsError(.Value)` (true if cell value is a `Variant/Error`, which `#N/A` is), and then to compare that error value with `CVErr(xlErrNA)` to branch execution when the error is specifically a `#N/A` error. That said the biggest problem with your original code is that the expression "If X = A Or B" should read "If X = A Or X = B" to work as intended, otherwise you're bitwise-Or'ing the B expression with the Boolean result of =A.

Comment: ^^^^ @Mento, yeah that's what the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code) in my first comment demonstrates. So that's the more thorough approach, agree with Mathieu.