# Excel VBA - Copying cells in a row up to non-error value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy cells from a fixed column from another workbook to the main (thisWorkbook). I am able to write the VBA code for opening/accessing the other workbook.

Assuming the number of rows is uncertain, and the typical source workbook looks like the below. How do I select up to the last row that doesn't contain error (N/A) value and then copy it over to my main workbook.

[image]

Comment: A little research is important before asking questions here. I googled "how to test for cell errors in excel vba" and got https://excelchamps.com/vba/functions/iserror/ and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code) post in SO.

Comment: For selecting out of A1:A100 of Sheet1 up to the cell before first formula error --`Range(Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)(1).Offset(-1), Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)(1).Offset(-1).End(xlUp)).Select`

Comment: You could use the classic “last row” snippets if you just surround your original formulas with `IFNA(formula,"")` so you never `#N/A` get in your results to begin with