# How does VBA interpret #N/A error values and how can we use "N/A" errors in a conditional loop?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to create a conditional loop in VBA where the script will input a specific formula base on the location.
If the branch is from Quebec (or Cell value = "QC")it will add this function:
="IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],7),1,1)=""*"",IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],4),1,1)=""*"",RIGHT(RC[-2],3),""NOR""),""NOR"")"

If the branch is not from quebec, I will add this function instead:
=IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],6),1,1)=""*"",IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],3),1,1)=""*"",RIGHT(RC[-2],2),""NOR""),""NOR"")"

The loop works however once the loop encounter's a "#N/A" value in the branch column, I will get an "Runtime error '13' Type Mismatch" error message.

**My questions is:** How does VBA interpret "#N/A" values?  Does anyone know if we can incorporate "#N/A" values as a part of the loop criteria? I dont mind if the script inputs the second function as "#N/A" means the item is not from Quebec.

```
Sub Branch()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Branch"
Range("M2").Select
'To set up the variables for last row and creating a counter
Dim LR As Long
Dim CounterB As Long

'This formula determines the value of the last row of the cell

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Counter is used to  determine the position of the active cell in the loop
CounterB = 2

'This is allow the script to know when to stop
Do Until CounterB = LR + 1

'This is to set the starting position of the loop
Range("M" & CounterB).Select

'This is to add the formula depending on if this is from Quebec region or not (script stops once it encounters a #N/A)
If Range("O" & CounterB).Value = "CL-OPS-PLAN-QC" Then
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],7),1,1)=""_"",IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],4),1,1)=""_"",RIGHT(RC[-2],3),""NOR""),""NOR"")"
    CounterB = CounterB + 1

Else
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],6),1,1)=""_"",IF(MID(RIGHT(RC[-2],3),1,1)=""_"",RIGHT(RC[-2],2),""NOR""),""NOR"")"
    CounterB = CounterB + 1
End If
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values

Comment: You can assign value you want to check for N/A to some variant variable , lets say `dim v as variant` and do checks `if IsError(v) then: if v = CVErr(xlErrNA) then: ....`

Comment: Also, check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143402/checking-for-n-a-in-excel-cell-from-vba-code

Comment: You can easily fix this with `If CStr(Range("O" & CounterB).Value) = ...`. Instead of writing `CounterB = CounterB + 1` in each `If` clause, you can just use it after (right before `Loop`). But using a `For...Next` loop instead would be more readable: `For CounterB = 2 To LR` ... `Next LR` when the loop would increment the `CounterB` by one. Also, you don't need to use `Select` and `ActiveCell` (it slows down the code); just use `Range("M" & CounterB).FormulaR1C1 = ...`.

Comment: If you don't want to write the formula if an error is in the cell, you can use `If Not IsError(Range("O" & CounterB)) Then` to check if the cell's value isn't an error value,  or `If VarType(Range("O" & CounterB).Value) = vbString Then` to check if the cell value is a string.